# Are IP-addreses classful or classless?

Tags: networking, network-programming, network-protocols

Given an IP datagram, how can one elucidate whether the IP address' are classful or classless?
Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: how does this relate to programming?

Comment: writing an program to acquire information about a network from captured packets. Frankly, I kind of expected a close, but was hoping an answer or two would sneak in before the door slammed shut.

Comment: networking questions are more welcome on ServerFault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all classless these days.

Comment: Yeah, i figured. So for classless addressing, how could the subnet mask be determined given a datagram?

Comment: You can't. Unless it's local and you can query the router (ICMP netmask). Or look at the configs.